# Merge Jacoco results, obfuscated and not obfuscated runs

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, proguard, jacoco

We have a multi module Android project which contains the app module, library modules and test modules(to test library modules with the app).
We are facing an issue, that we can't merge the coverage results because of class mismatches.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Different class names com/xxx/xxx/common/model/cblite/ViewCreator and com/xxx/xxx/common/model/cblite/d for id 98bd81913c1da431.

This mismatch is caused by the obfuscation. We want to run our tests on the obfuscated app to test the obfuscation as well.
But when we test library modules directly, they can't be obfuscated.

The merge Task looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

task jacocoRootReport(type: JacocoReport, group: 'Coverage reports') {
    project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {

        def sourceSet = []
        def sourceClasses = []

        subprojects.each { subproject ->
            if (subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.application') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.library')) {
                subproject.android.sourceSets.each { set ->
                    sourceSet.add(set.java.srcDirs)
                }
            }

            def variants
            if (subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.application')) {
                variants = subproject.android.applicationVariants
            } else if (subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('com.android.library')) {
                variants = subproject.android.libraryVariants
            }

            if (variants) {
                variants.each { variant ->
                    def compileTask = variant.getJavaCompileProvider().get()
                    sourceClasses.add(compileTask.destinationDir)
                }
            }
        }

        additionalSourceDirs = files(sourceSet)
        sourceDirectories = files(sourceSet)
        jacocoClasspath = configurations['jacocoAnt']
        classDirectories = files(files(sourceClasses).collect {
            fileTree(dir: it, exclude: ['**/R.class',
                                        '**/R$*.class',
                                        '**/*__Factory.class',
                                        '**/*__MemberInjector.class',
                                        '**/MemberInjectorRegistry.class',
                                        '**/FactoryRegistry.class',
                                        '**/*Test*.class',
                                        '**/BuildConfig.*'

            ])
        })

        executionData = fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/*.ec", "**/*.exec")

        reports {
            html.enabled = true
            xml.enabled = true
            html.destination = file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco")
            xml.destination = file("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/report.xml")
        }
    }
}
```

We also tried to use the jenkins jacoco plugin and merge the results there. But his does not work as well because of the same error.

Is there any possibility to merge the results?

Comment: I'd just run coverage measurement tests on unobfuscated variants and have separate tests without coverage instrumentation for obfuscated app testing if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the idea.
We had the same idea as a workaround but our tests take one hour to run. So running them twice would result in a build time of more then 2 hours.
This is not a really good option for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the proguard parameter "-adaptclassstrings" caused this issue.
After removing this from the config, the jacoco results contain the original names again, so the merging works as well.